# Webscraping Multiple JS pages at once

Tags: json, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to webscrape a website that has multiple pages that are rendered by Javascript. I am using BeautifulSoup and Selenium. I have a script that works but only for the first page of the website. Is it possible to webscrape multiple javascript rendered pages or do I need to do them individually?  Here is my script:

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import json

# The path to where you have your chrome webdriver stored:
webdriver_path = '/Users/rawlins/Downloads/chromedriver'

# Add arguments telling Selenium to not actually open a window
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
#chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1920x1080')

# Fire up the headless browser
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = webdriver_path,
chrome_options = chrome_options)

# Load webpage
url = "https://cnx.org/search?q=subject:Arts"
browser.get(url)

# to ensure that the page has loaded completely.
time.sleep(3)

data = [] 
n = 2
for i in range(1, n+1):
    if (i == 1):
        # handle first page
        response = requests.get(url)
    response = requests.get(url + "&page=" + str(i))
    #response = requests.get(url + "&page=" + str(i),headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'})

    # Parse HTML, close browser
    page_soup = soup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
    containers = page_soup.findAll("tr")
    browser.quit()

    for container in containers:
        item = {}
        item['type'] = "Course Material"
        if container.find('td', {'class' : 'title'}):
            item['title'] = container.find('td', {'class' : 'title'}).h4.text.strip()
        else:
            item['title'] = ""
        if container.find('td', {'class' : 'authors'}):
            item['author'] = container.find('td', {'class' : 'authors'}).text.strip()
        else:
            item['author'] = ""
        if container.find('td', {'class' : 'title'}):
            item['link'] = "https://cnx.org/" + container.find('td', {'class' : 'title'}).a["href"]
        else: 
            item['link'] = ""
        if container.find('td', {'class' : 'title'}):
            item['description'] = container.find('td', {'class' : 'title'}).span.text
        else: 
            item['description'] = ""
        item['subject'] = "Arts"
        item['source'] = "OpenStax CNX"
        item['base_url'] = "https://cnx.org/browse"
        item['license'] = "Attribution"
        data.append(item) # add the item to the list

    with open("js-webscrape.json", "w") as writeJSON:
        json.dump(data, writeJSON, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of issues here:

- You're mixing `requests.get()` in with `browser.get()`. No need for the `requests` module at all here since you're getting the page via the headless browser.
- No need to have a special case for the first page. https://cnx.org/search?q=subject:Arts&page=1 works fine.
- `time.sleep()` should be between `browser.get()` and the parsing, to allow the page to fully load before feeding it to BeautifulSoup.
- You should write `data` to the JSON file outside the `for` loop, once all pages have been scraped.
- Quit the browser outside the `for` loop as well, not after a single iteration.
- To avoid encoding errors, specify the encoding when writing to the JSON file: with `open("js-webscrape.json", "w", encoding="utf-8")`

Here's a working implementation that scrapes all 7 pages:

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import json

# The path to where you have your chrome webdriver stored:
webdriver_path = '/Users/Gebruiker/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver'

# Add arguments telling Selenium to not actually open a window
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

# Fire up the headless browser
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = webdriver_path, options = chrome_options)

# Load webpage
url = "https://cnx.org/search?q=subject:Arts"

data = []
n = 7
for i in range(1, n+1):
    response = browser.get(url + "&page=" + str(i))
    time.sleep(5)

    # Parse HTML
    page_soup = soup(browser.page_source,'lxml')
    containers = page_soup.findAll("tr")

    for container in containers:
        item = dict()
        item['type'] = "Course Material"
        if container.find('td', {'class' : 'title'}):
            item['title'] = container.find('td', {'class' : 'title'}).h4.text.strip()
        else:
            item['title'] = ""
        if container.find('td', {'class' : 'authors'}):
            item['author'] = container.find('td', {'class' : 'authors'}).text.strip()
        else:
            item['author'] = ""
        if container.find('td', {'class' : 'title'}):
            item['link'] = "https://cnx.org/" + container.find('td', {'class' : 'title'}).a["href"]
        else:
            item['link'] = ""
        if container.find('td', {'class' : 'title'}):
            item['description'] = container.find('td', {'class' : 'title'}).span.text
        else:
            item['description'] = ""
        item['subject'] = "Arts"
        item['source'] = "OpenStax CNX"
        item['base_url'] = "https://cnx.org/browse"
        item['license'] = "Attribution"
        data.append(item) # add the item to the list

# write data to file and quit browser when done
print(data)
with open("js-webscrape.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as writeJSON:
    json.dump(data, writeJSON, ensure_ascii=False)

browser.quit()
```